# React restore the component with previous state on browser back button

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

In react app, I am showing a list of data(fetched through paginated API calls using InfiniteScroll) where user can click on any of the item to view the details. When the user press browser back button from the details page and goes back to list page, all the previously fetched data from the API calls are lost and the screen goes to the top of the list. Is it possible to retain all the data and scroll position for the user when user goes back to the list page from the detail page.

```
<BrowserRouter basename={'/'} >
            <Switch>
                    <Route exact path={`/list`} component={List} />
                    <Route exact path={`/list/details`} component={ListDetails} />
            </Switch>
</BrowserRouter>
```

and redirecting using

```
    const history = useHistory();
    history.push({
            pathname: '/list/details',
            search: `?item=${id}`,
        });
```

`react-router-dom` version `5.1.2`

Comment: What do you use for state management ?

Comment: You can persist the state *somewhere* and re-populate when the component mounts.

Comment: For one of the app I worked on previously, this was handled without storing the data(unfortunately can't check the code for it now). Seems it was handled by the browser, so I was wondering if I missed something here. If nothing works, will persist and re-populate the data.